# The Julia 1.0 On-Line Documentation Search Engine

Tags: julia

If I type a search term into the Julia 1.0 on-line documentation search box, it takes about 5 or 6 seconds to come back with suggested answers.

If I do the same search for an old version of Julia, for example version 0.3.12, the suggested answers come back almost immediately.

I downloaded and started coding Julia at version 1.0.0, so I do not know the history of what is happening here.

Has there been a significant decrease in the speed of the Julia on-line documentation?

Comment: I think you will get more attention at https://discourse.julialang.org

Comment: Okay, thanks for the link.  I am new to Julia, so if I am the only one having this problem or observation, it would be nice to know.  But maybe others are also experiencing the same thing, which might give my observation more weight.  However, your suggestion is appreciated.

Comment: Yes, it's a known issue. The newer docs are searched client-side, which can be slow. There are several related discussions at the Documenter repo: https://github.com/JuliaDocs/Documenter.jl

Comment: @IsaiahNorton Thanks for the info Isaiah.  I'll check it out.

Comment: Might I also suggest [devdocs.io](http://devdocs.io) for Julia 1.0 documentation? Supports offline documentation as well.